# How do I verify that a string is in English?

Tags: c#, string, character-encoding

I read a string from the console.  How do I make sure it only contains English characters and digits?

Comment: What are “English characters” for you (let alone the fact that scripts and languages are quite different things and English uses the Latin script)? “naïve” is a perfectly valid English word, yet it contains one non-ASCII letter. If your domain is indeed “string of English words” then you have to be way more careful than if you just mean “strings of ASCII letters and digits”.

Comment: Slightly surpised that nine people think this question is 'useful and clear' when "only contains English characters and digits" is so very very ambiguous...

Comment: @Akash: Well, the requirement as it is now, is pretty much useless. I can't think of any reasonable thing that might need to constrain strings to “English characters” (which, in my eyes would mean “characters that are needed to write English texts”). That would of course include punctuation, various variants of Latin base characters (cedilla, diaeresis, &c.) as well as probably presentation forms like ligatures. Of course, with that constraints in mind you can perfectly well write many other European languages with that set of characters.

Comment: I think he meant what he said, a list of english character only... to my knowledge, english word do not uses anything else then the 26 letters of the latin alphabet except for imported words. I'de restrict myself to what can be written using a normal english keyboard and forget the éàôï and others of the sort.

Comment: As the question is currently written, answers must identify as English "façade", "naîve", etc.

Comment: @JaredBeck : No.  The English word is "facade" spell with a C.  "façade" spelled with a c-cedilla is merely a foreign which the English word is based.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Assuming that by "English characters" you are simply referring to the 26-character Latin alphabet, this would be an area where I would use regular expressions:  `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$`

For example:

```
if( Regex.IsMatch(Console.ReadLine(), "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$") )
{ /* your code */ }
```

The benefit of regular expressions in this case is that all you really care about is whether or not a string matches a pattern - this is one where regular expressions work wonderfully. It clearly captures your intent, and it's easy to extend if you definition of "English characters" expands beyond just the 26 alphabetic ones.

There's a decent [series of articles here](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/regexlearnsyntax.aspx) that teach more about regular expressions.

Jørn Schou-Rode's answer provides a great explanation of how the regular expression presented here works to match your input.

Comment: You may want to include white space as well; "a b c" returns false for the given regex pattern.

Comment: And what about fancy punctuation characters like the ellipsis character (…) or curly apostrophes? These have their own unicode characters.

Comment: This incorrect answer mistakenly equates ASCII with “English”.  It is incredibly wrong — as this comment plainly demonstrates.

Answer (score 20):

You could match it against this regular expression: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`

- `^` matches the start of the string (ie no characters are allowed before this point)
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches any letter from a-z in lower or upper case, as well as digits 0-9
- `*` lets the previous match repeat zero or more times
- `$` matches the end of the string (ie no characters are allowed after this point)

To use the expression in a C# program, you will need to import `System.Text.RegularExpressions` and do something like this in your code:

```
bool match = Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
```

If you are going to test a lot of lines against the pattern, you might want to compile the expression:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    pattern.IsMatch(input);
}
```

Comment: Note that this pattern will return false if the input string contains a space.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer does not work for the white spaces or punctuation. Below code is tested for this input:

> Hello: 1. - a; b/c \ _(5)??
> (*Is English*)

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9. -_?]*$");


string text1 = "سلام";
bool fls = regex.IsMatch(text1);   //false

string text2 = "123 abc! ?? -_)(/\\;:";
bool tru = regex.IsMatch(text2);  //true
```

Answer (score 5):

One other way is to check if `IsLower` and `IsUpper` both doesn't return true. Something like:

```
private bool IsAllCharEnglish(string Input)
{
 foreach (var item in Input.ToCharArray())
 {
  if (!char.IsLower(item) && !char.IsUpper(item) && !char.IsDigit(item) && !char.IsWhiteSpace(item))
  {
      return false;
  }
 }
 return true;
}
```

And for use it :

```
string str = "فارسی abc";
IsAllCharEnglish(str); // return false

str = "These are english 123";
IsAllCharEnglish(str); // return true
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it returns true for languages like Russian with lowercased/uppercased letters.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use RegEx and LINQ they are slower than the loop by characters of string

[Performance test](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qv61xu)

My solution:

```
private static bool is_only_eng_letters_and_digits(string str)
{
   foreach (char ch in str)
   {
      if (!(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') && !(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') && !(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'))
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

do you have web access? i would assume that cannot be guaranteed, but Google has a language api that will detect the language you pass to it.
[google language api](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Translation)

Answer (score 1):

```
bool onlyEnglishCharacters = !EnglishText.Any(a => a > '~');
```

Seems cheap, but it worked for me, legit easy answer.
Hope it helps anyone.

Comment: `NUL`, `BEL` and other low-end ASCII characters are all less than "~" - which makes this much more brittle than it needs to be.  Add an `|| a < '0'` and you'd be closer to a solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool AllAscii(string str)
{ 
   return !str.Any(c => !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
}
```

Comment: IsLetterOrDigit will be true for any Unicode letter. Not only for English. Am I correct?

Comment: It has false result according to what I test.

Comment: Char.IsLetterOrDigit doesn't appear to distinguish between Western alphabets and others. Using Char.IsLetterOrDIgit here is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (if you want to control input):

```
static string ReadLettersAndDigits() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
    while ((keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true)).Key != ConsoleKey.Enter) {
        char c = char.ToLower(keyInfo.KeyChar);
        if (('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || char.IsDigit(c)) {
            sb.Append(keyInfo.KeyChar);
            Console.Write(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i dont wnat to use RegEx, and just to provide an alternate solution, you can just check the ASCII code of each character and if it lies between that range, it would either be a english letter or a number (This might not be the best solution):

```
foreach (char ch in str.ToCharArray()) 
{ 
    int x = (int)char;
    if (x >= 63 and x <= 126) 
    {
       //this is english letter, i.e.- A, B, C, a, b, c...
    }
    else if(x >= 48 and x <= 57)
    {
       //this is number
    }
    else
    {
       //this is something diffrent
    }

}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII for full ASCII table.

But I still think, RegEx is the best solution.

Comment: This incorrect answer mistakenly conflates ASCII with “English”.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the Regular Expression answers. However, you could simplify it to just "^[\w]+$". \w is any "word character" (which translates to [a-zA-Z_0-9] if you use a non-unicode alphabet. I don't know if you want underscores as well.

More on regexes in .net here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx#regexnet_topic8

Answer (score 0):

As many pointed out, accepted answer works only if there is a single word in the string. As there are no answers that cover the case of multiple words or even sentences in the string, here is the code:

```
stringToCheck.Any(x=> char.IsLetter(x) && !((int)x >= 63 && (int)x <= 126));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $string="हिन्दी";
    $string="Manvendra Rajpurohit";
    echo strlen($string); echo '<br>';
    echo mb_strlen($string, 'utf-8');
    echo '<br>';
    if(strlen($string) != mb_strlen($string, 'utf-8'))
    { 
        echo "Please enter English words only:(";
    }
    else {
        echo "OK, English Detected!";
    }
?>
```