# How to get Language Code from a String in Flutter | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-plugin

I'am creating a social media platform. So there is a comment section. I created a translating function to translate any language comment to english (like in instagram or youtube). But the problem is if the language in the comment is already in english i don't want to show the 'Translate' button below to that comment. So how can i detect the language or language code from that comment to make this functionality. Is there any package available to detect the language code from the string.

Eg: If the comment is 'Hello how are you'. Then i dont want to show that translate button under this comment. But if the comment is 'नमस्ते कैसी हो तुम. I want to show translate button. I want to detect wheather the language is in english 'en' or not.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/2266102/2804581

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and following link helped me to get these things successfully-
[How to get timezone, Language and County Id in flutter by the location of device in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923906/how-to-get-timezone-language-and-county-id-in-flutter-by-the-location-of-device)